# Broad Interface Implementation (& general design pattern help)

Tags: php, design-patterns, interface

My question is closely related to [Interface Implementation (Interface Segregation Principle)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7852418/interface-implementation-interface-segregation-principle) but I'd greatly appreciate some more advice.

I've got two postage APIs that provide postage quotes - the only thing in common is soap.
I've written my application code to interact with these APIs by writing a 'Postage Driver' interface which both wrapped up APIs implement. I then use a 'Postage Calculator' class which makes use of these 'Drivers' via their common interface in order to calculate postage costs with out knowing exactly how it's done.

My question is, these API are so different (one needs credentials passed in as method parameters while the other uses xml files for credentials, one calculates postage cost on total weight while the other calculates it on package details) that I'm unsure if using interfaces to abstract my code is the best way? It's starting to feel like coding conditional code into the 'Postage Calculator' class and using the APIs directly would be cleaner and more elegant (albeit less flexible and future proof).

Any advice would be welcome. Btw, I'm writing in PHP but I'm after more 'general principles' advice.

Comment: IMHO, the fact that they are so different is an _excellent_ reason to hide it behind an interface. However, I wouldn't make it to specific: create functions that take a whole order/shipment as argument, let them figure out themselves what details they need from this. I'm in the (debatable) camp of: _"if one method of your interface doesn't make sense for the other implementation, it isn't abstract enough"_.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the Wrikken, you can always pass in an authentication interface to the postage interface .  Then you are just passing off the difference to the class that is really different.

In the same vein, you could create interfaces for calculating postage, perhaps IPostageSpecificationByWeight and IPostageBy?.  Then you can inject them into a baseclass or interface that your services use.

You can handle this same concept with an abstract class that implements the authentication methods and calculation methods in the derived class where the common methods that use them are in the abstract class and then you just have one interface.  There are plenty of ways to abstract this away and these are just a couple of options.